# if else statement wont work java

Tags: java, swing

The question field should contain 36 questions, the answer to these question are on the 36 buttons in the grid.

When the user selects the clicks the correct button answer the button is taken off the grid, the aim is to clear the grid so the grid is empty.

if the user clicks an incorrect button the game restarts.

**i am having a problem with adding the question label.**

**the question field should display 36 question starting with what is 0 + 1 when the user clicks the correct button it then shows 
question 2 shows in the field which is what is 1+1 and so till question 36**

i have tried to get this by Changing this line of code

```
 gui.statusLabel.setText("what is 0+ 1" + gui.buttonCounter);
```

to this:

```
 gui.statusLabel.setText("what is " + gui.buttonCounter + "+ 1");
```

but the games doesnt work properly although the correct answer is selected the code keeps saying doing the "else" in this code ie. Incorrect button clicked, start again: what is 0+ 1

```
    if(clickedNumber == gui.buttonCounter){
        gui.buttonCounter++;
        buttonClicked.setText("");//optional - clears correct selection
        if(gui.buttonCounter > gui.ROWS*gui.COLUMNS) gui.reset();
        gui.statusLabel.setText("what is 0+ 1" + gui.buttonCounter);
    } else {
        gui.reset();
        gui.statusLabel.setText("Incorrect button clicked, start again: what is 0+ 1");
    }

    }
}
```

how do i fix this? so when i click the correct answer button it moves to the next question and does not display Incorrect button clicked, start again: what is 0+ 1.

full code

```
class NewClass {

    final int ROWS = 6;
    final int COLUMNS = 6;
    JButton[] buttons = new JButton[ROWS * COLUMNS];
    JLabel statusLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
    java.util.List<Integer> buttonNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int buttonCounter = 1;

    public NewClass() {
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLUMNS));
        ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener(NewClass.this);
        for (int x = 0, y = ROWS * COLUMNS; x < y; x++) {
            buttons[x] = new JButton();
            buttons[x].addActionListener(listener);
            buttonPanel.add(buttons[x]);
            buttonNumbers.add(new Integer(x + 1));
        }
        reset();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(statusLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void reset() {
        Collections.shuffle(buttonNumbers);
        for (int x = 0, y = ROWS * COLUMNS; x < y; x++) {
            buttons[x].setText(String.valueOf(buttonNumbers.get(x)));
        }
        buttonCounter = 1;
        statusLabel.setText("Please click button  " + buttonCounter);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NewClass();
    }

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        NewClass gui;

        ButtonListener(NewClass g) {
            gui = g;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JButton buttonClicked = (JButton) e.getSource();
            int clickedNumber = Integer.parseInt(buttonClicked.getText());
            if (clickedNumber == gui.buttonCounter) {
                gui.buttonCounter++;
                buttonClicked.setText("");// optional - clears correct selection
                if (gui.buttonCounter > gui.ROWS * gui.COLUMNS)
                    gui.reset();
                // gui.statusLabel.setText("Please click button" +
                // gui.buttonCounter);

                gui.statusLabel.setText("what is " + buttonCounter);

            } else {
                gui.reset();
                gui.statusLabel
                        .setText("Incorrect button clicked, start again: 0 + 1");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the question is "what is [button counter] + 1" why would the condition be clickedNumber == [button counter]? wouldn't it be clickedNumber == [button counter] + 1?

Comment: Add a break point in you `actionPerformed` method and debug it...

Comment: i am adding the full code. i did change what you suggested but its still with the same error.

Comment: You sure that clickedNumber and gui.buttonCounter are what you think? Have you debugged as suggested?

Answer (score 3):

So, taking the code from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22977030/jlabel-and-swap-the-text-it-holds-via-the-jlabels-settext-method) and adding

```
System.out.println("ClickedNumber = " + clickedNumber);
System.out.println("gui.buttonCounter = " + gui.buttonCounter);
```

Into the `actionPerformed` method it asks...

"What is 0+1 1" (which should be "What is 0+1").  I click "1", which outputs...

```
ClickedNumber = 1
gui.buttonCounter = 1
```

So looking at the `if` statement;

```
if (clickedNumber == gui.buttonCounter) {
```

This is `true`...

Then it asks...

"What is 2+1".  I click "3", which outputs...

```
ClickedNumber = 3
gui.buttonCounter = 2
```

So looking at the `if` statement;

```
if (clickedNumber == gui.buttonCounter) {
```

Which is `false`.

There is a logic error in your code.  Basically, it's coming down to you not actually knowing what the question is...

**Runnable example**

Basically what this does is asks...

> "What is " + buttonCounter + "+1"?

In the `if` condition, we assume the `buttonCounter` is `0` indexed, meaning we need to increase the comparison by 1

```
if (clickedNumber == (gui.buttonCounter + 1)) {
```

Or you could reduce the `clickedNumeber` by 1

```
if ((clickedNumber - 1) == gui.buttonCounter) {
```

Remember, you question is always asks "What's the next number", not what's the current number...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class NewClass {

    final int ROWS = 6;
    final int COLUMNS = 6;
    JButton[] buttons = new JButton[ROWS * COLUMNS];
    JLabel statusLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
    java.util.List<Integer> buttonNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int buttonCounter = 1;

    public NewClass() {
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLUMNS));
        ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener(NewClass.this);
        for (int x = 0, y = ROWS * COLUMNS; x < y; x++) {
            buttons[x] = new JButton();
            buttons[x].addActionListener(listener);
            buttonPanel.add(buttons[x]);
            buttonNumbers.add(new Integer(x + 1));
        }
        reset();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(statusLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void reset() {
        Collections.shuffle(buttonNumbers);
        for (int x = 0, y = ROWS * COLUMNS; x < y; x++) {
            buttons[x].setText(String.valueOf(buttonNumbers.get(x)));
        }
        buttonCounter = 0;
        statusLabel.setText("Please click button  " + buttonCounter + "+1");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NewClass();
    }

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        NewClass gui;

        ButtonListener(NewClass g) {
            gui = g;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JButton buttonClicked = (JButton) e.getSource();
            int clickedNumber = Integer.parseInt(buttonClicked.getText());

            System.out.println("ClickedNumber = " + clickedNumber);
            System.out.println("gui.buttonCounter = " + gui.buttonCounter);
            if (clickedNumber == (gui.buttonCounter + 1)) {
                gui.buttonCounter++;
                buttonClicked.setText("");// optional - clears correct selection
                if (gui.buttonCounter > gui.ROWS * gui.COLUMNS) {
                    gui.reset();
                }
                // gui.statusLabel.setText("Please click button" +
                // gui.buttonCounter);

                gui.statusLabel.setText("what is " + buttonCounter + "+1");

            } else {
                gui.reset();
                gui.statusLabel
                        .setText("Incorrect button clicked, start again: 0 + 1");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Updated with winner condition**

```
if (clickedNumber == (gui.buttonCounter + 1)) {
    if (gui.buttonCounter == (gui.ROWS * gui.COLUMNS) - 1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Win", "Winner", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    } else {
        gui.buttonCounter++;
        buttonClicked.setText("");// optional - clears correct selection
        if (gui.buttonCounter > gui.ROWS * gui.COLUMNS) {
            gui.reset();
        }
        // gui.statusLabel.setText("Please click button" +
        // gui.buttonCounter);

        gui.statusLabel.setText("what is " + buttonCounter + "+1");
    }
} else {
    gui.reset();
    gui.statusLabel
            .setText("Incorrect button clicked, start again: 0 + 1");
}
```

Comment: what is the question? my english is not very good i am trying my best. please help me if you understand what i am trying to say

Comment: Your `if` statement doesn't work.  The first question asks "What is 0+1" which is `1`, this works.  The second questions asks "What is 2+1" which is `3`, but your `if` statement is expecting `2` which what the `gui.buttonCounter` value is.  One of those two conditions is wrong, which one will come down to what you want to achieve...

Comment: See the update, I making assumptions based on what I "think" you're trying to do...

Comment: Apart from the text output, you'd need to change your `if` statement to be more like `gui.buttonCounter + 2`.  What might a better idea is to actually calculate the expected answer ;)

Comment: you know the buttons do u think i can change the textsyle or add an image to it?

Comment: Start by checking out [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Comment: Well, presumably you know how many buttons there are and you know which button they are up to.  You just need to compare those two values and when they are equal, you win...

Comment: You won't need the for loop, but something more like `if (buttonCounter == ROWS * COLUMNS) { // You win }`

Comment: were abouts wouldi add this

Comment: The would depend.  I'd be tempted to put it before `gui.buttonCounter++;` and in fact, that section of code would become the `else` condition

Comment: i got this error.Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable ROWS
  location: class javaapplication24.ButtonListener

Comment: ive done that.. just how do you write the joption code.. this is wher i have error

Comment: Theres a difference between what you code is trying to run and what it has available within the classes.

Comment: srry i dont understand

Comment: What Java is trying to run is not what is available, you have a class mismatch, something hasn't built properly...You have stale or out of date classes

Comment: i have fixed it but please can you look at the updated code because i dont think i have put the else statement in the right place

Comment: You seriously need to read out each if statement out aloud and walk the conditions to determine if they are doing what you want...check update...

Comment: the joption still doesnt work.. its the "this" in the statement which is giving an error saying incompatible types: ButtonListener cannot be converted to Component
----

Comment: You seriously need to learn how to use a debugger, check update to last example

Comment: are  u gettin mad at me?

Comment: Kind of- The last problem would have been solved by taking a look at the comparison between the `gui.buttonCounter` and `(gui.ROWS * gui.COLUMNS)`, which is all I did, which highlighted the fact that I didn't take into account the fact that `gui.buttonCounter` starts at `0`. A lot of the problems you're having could have been solved with a debugger and/or `System.out` statements, these are skills you will need for future, more complex projects...

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I don't mind helping, but I would have been more impressed if you had come back to me and told me not only what the problem was, but what you thought the solution should be, right or wrong ;)

Comment: if i wanted to have random question so its not always + 1 is this possible? also how do i get a timer to work within this?

Comment: These are complex questions, the problem is, you need to know the answer you are looking for BEFORE the user responds, you also need to know what possible answers are available, it keeps getting complex, what happens when you want to use a random modifier (in instead of just addition).  Adding a `Timer` is also a complex question